# Connect to Local web services from my android device

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin Android Application.I want to connect my android device to a local web service and want to work with it.How to do that ?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/

Comment: I have read it.But how to connect to local web services?@Jason

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what specific problems you're having.  There is nothing special about a "local" web service vs a "remote" one, unless you are running them in a web server that does not allow remote connections.